# My Android App Keeps Crashing When Opening A New Activity From My Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, xml

I am new to coding in Android Studio and have been trying to make an application for school. I have made a navigation drawer that launches a few new activities. Right now, it only launches two activities which are the settings activity (which has nothing in it yet) and my basketball tutorial home page activity. Whenever I launch the settings activity, the activity shows up and the application does not crash. However, when I click on my basketball tutorial home page activity, the app crashes for some reason. This activity contains the beginning of almost like a youtube like structure, where once you click on the buttons, it sends you to the video. I also have a splash screen that launches my main activity. Please help in anyway you can. It was not letting me add the imports for the java file onto this forum, so I have let them out, as well as the public class....extends....as it was not working. The whole file also comes up with no errors.

Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jehan.sportstutorials" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Sports Tutorials"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".Splash" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="Sports Tutorials" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.default" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="Settings"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".basketball_tutorial_home_page"
            android:label="Basketball Tutorials"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Main Activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="@bool/fitsSystemWindows">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/status_bar_kitkat_height"
            android:background="?colorPrimary"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="?colorPrimaryDark"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Welcome To Sports Tutorials!"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
            android:textColor="@color/md_text"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textIsSelectable="false" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
            android:text="Just Swipe Left To Get Started!"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
            android:textColor="@color/md_text"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@drawable/action_bar_color"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="@bool/fitsSystemWindows"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer_menu"
        app:theme="@style/NavigationViewTheme" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Main Activity Java:

```
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
Toolbar toolbar;
ActionBar actionBar;
TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_white_24dp);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)        findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer_layout);

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    if (navigationView != null) {
        setupNavigationDrawerContent(navigationView);
    }

    setupNavigationDrawerContent(navigationView);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void setupNavigationDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.item_navigation_drawer_basketball:
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            textView.setText(menuItem.getTitle());
                            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, basketball_tutorial_home_page.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            return true;
                        case R.id.item_navigation_drawer_starred:
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            textView.setText(menuItem.getTitle());
                            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            return true;
                        case R.id.item_navigation_drawer_sent_mail:
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            textView.setText(menuItem.getTitle());
                            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            return true;
                        case R.id.item_navigation_drawer_drafts:
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            textView.setText(menuItem.getTitle());
                            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            return true;
                        case R.id.item_navigation_drawer_settings:
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            textView.setText(menuItem.getTitle());
                            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent1);
                            return true;
                        case R.id.item_navigation_drawer_help:
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, menuItem.getTitle().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                            return true;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
}
```

Basketball Tutorial Home Page xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/md_divider">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="?colorPrimary"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:background="@drawable/action_bar_color"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="509dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/md_divider"
        android:padding="7dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00FF00"
            android:elevation="4dp">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"
                android:background="#00FF00"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:elevation="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_shooting_tutorial"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#00FF00">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="Basketball Shooting Tutorial"
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:theme="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:gravity="start|bottom"
                    android:background="#00FF00"
                    android:inputType="text" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="Length: 04:43"
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:theme="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="italic"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:background="#00FF00"
                    android:inputType="time"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

Basketball Tutorial Java:

```
Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_basketball_tutorial_home_page);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    TypedValue typedValueColorPrimaryDark = new TypedValue();
    basketball_tutorial_home_page.this.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorPrimaryDark, typedValueColorPrimaryDark, true);
    final int colorPrimaryDark = typedValueColorPrimaryDark.data;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(colorPrimaryDark);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_basketball_tutorial_home_page, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_bar) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Navigation Drawer Menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:checked="true"
            android:id="@+id/item_navigation_drawer_basketball"
            android:icon="@drawable/basketball_drawer"
            android:title="Basketball" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/item_navigation_drawer_starred"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_toggle_star"
            android:title="Starred" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/item_navigation_drawer_sent_mail"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_content_send"
            android:title="Sent mail" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/item_navigation_drawer_drafts"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_content_drafts"
            android:title="Drafts" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="More">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/item_navigation_drawer_settings"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_action_settings"
                android:title="Settings" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/item_navigation_drawer_help"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_action_help"
                android:title="Help" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Here is the log of the app:

```
07-13 12:30:34.823    1011-1018/com.jehan.sportstutorials W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 8.605ms
07-13 12:30:34.896    1011-1023/com.jehan.sportstutorials I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3067(319KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 1511KB/1511KB, paused 23.822ms total 134.618ms
07-13 12:30:34.922    1011-1023/com.jehan.sportstutorials W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 25.693ms
07-13 12:30:35.187    1011-1023/com.jehan.sportstutorials I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 349(33KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 40% free, 1477KB/2MB, paused 3.349ms total 132.790ms
07-13 12:30:35.201    1011-1018/com.jehan.sportstutorials W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 5.092ms
07-13 12:30:38.036    1011-1011/com.jehan.sportstutorials I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 1011 SIG: 9
07-13 12:30:52.636    1153-1173/com.jehan.sportstutorials D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
07-13 12:30:52.644    1153-1153/com.jehan.sportstutorials D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xae0c9580, tid 1153
07-13 12:30:52.724    1153-1153/com.jehan.sportstutorials D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
07-13 12:30:52.972    1153-1173/com.jehan.sportstutorials D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xae0c9e70, tid 1173
07-13 12:30:52.983    1153-1173/com.jehan.sportstutorials I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
07-13 12:30:53.003    1153-1173/com.jehan.sportstutorials D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
07-13 12:30:53.035    1153-1173/com.jehan.sportstutorials W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-13 12:30:53.035    1153-1173/com.jehan.sportstutorials W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6c4c640, error=EGL_SUCCESS
07-13 12:30:53.630    1153-1172/com.jehan.sportstutorials I/System.out﹕ 888.0
07-13 12:30:54.639    1153-1172/com.jehan.sportstutorials I/System.out﹕ 1073.4697
07-13 12:30:55.660    1153-1172/com.jehan.sportstutorials I/System.out﹕ 1252.9235
07-13 12:30:56.680    1153-1172/com.jehan.sportstutorials I/System.out﹕ 1437.9651
07-13 12:30:57.704    1153-1153/com.jehan.sportstutorials I/AppCompatViewInflater﹕ app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
07-13 12:30:57.731    1153-1153/com.jehan.sportstutorials I/AppCompatViewInflater﹕ app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
07-13 12:30:57.935    1153-1173/com.jehan.sportstutorials W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-13 12:30:57.935    1153-1173/com.jehan.sportstutorials W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6c4c660, error=EGL_SUCCESS
07-13 12:30:59.594    1153-1153/com.jehan.sportstutorials I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 94 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-13 12:31:03.214    1153-1153/com.jehan.sportstutorials I/AppCompatViewInflater﹕ app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
07-13 12:31:03.237    1153-1153/com.jehan.sportstutorials W/ResourceType﹕ Too many attribute references, stopped at: 0x01010099
07-13 12:31:03.238    1153-1153/com.jehan.sportstutorials W/ResourceType﹕ Too many attribute references, stopped at: 0x0101009a
07-13 12:31:03.238    1153-1153/com.jehan.sportstutorials W/ResourceType﹕ Too many attribute references, stopped at: 0x0101009b
07-13 12:31:03.255    1153-1153/com.jehan.sportstutorials D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
07-13 12:31:03.259    1153-1153/com.jehan.sportstutorials E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.jehan.sportstutorials, PID: 1153
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jehan.sportstutorials/com.jehan.sportstutorials.BasketballTutorial}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #53: Error inflating class Button
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #53: Error inflating class Button
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
at com.jehan.sportstutorials.BasketballTutorial.onCreate(BasketballTutorial.java:18)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
```

```
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 24
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:401)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:692)
at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:111)
at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:63)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:59)
at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:101)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:802)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:832)
at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
at com.jehan.sportstutorials.BasketballTutorial.onCreate(BasketballTutorial.java:18)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Please try to solve the problem quickly, as the project is due in about a week. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The logcat you posted does not include the crash. Look through your full logcat for an Exception.

Comment: Do you also learn to capitalize your full title on school?  :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Android Manifest you declare an Activity named `basketball_tutorial_home_page` here:

```
<activity
    android:name=".basketball_tutorial_home_page"
    android:label="Basketball Tutorials"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
</activity>
```

While you didn't specify what the name of the Basketball Tutorial's  Activity class actually is, I'm going to assume that you followed standards and that your Activity class name is UpperCamelCase (something like `BasketballTutorial`), whereas your layout XML file is snake_case (something like `basketball_tutorial_home_page.xml`).

If this is the case, then the problem is that you are not using the right name in your manifest. The `android:name` attribute needs to refer to the Java class, not the layout XML file. Thus this attribute should look more like `android:name=".BasketballTutorial"`.

Additionally, it looks like you have some odd attributes in your basketball tutorial XML, which may be causing the error your are seeing in your logcat.

- You are using `android:theme="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"`, which is overriding the entire theme for the buttons. You only want to override the text appearance using  `android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"`. Overriding the whole theme could result in some odd attributes
- `android:inputType` isn't needed for Buttons- since you can't input text into a button, setting an input type won't do anything.
- When using `android:layout_weight`, you should set either `android:layout_height` or `android:layout_width` to `0dp` to specify whether you want the width or the height to stretch.

Comment: I added a few notes on some odd layout attributes that you have that could be causing the logcat message you posted.

Answer (score 0):

"Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."
Try running in a new thread.

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        while(true) {
            sleep(1000);
            handler.post(this);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
};

thread.start();
```

Comment: Take a look at this page where it talks about threads.  It also shows good and different examples for running a different thread and how to use them.  http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html